# Scheduling service with alarm manager

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I wrote some simple classes to **schedule a service's start** and **end date.**

I got the following:

- **ServiceTest**: A simple service, logging onStart, onDestroy, and
  running.
- **ServiceSchedulerTest**: Scheduling ServiceTest's start and end
  date, using AlarmManager
- **ServiceStopBroadcastReceiverTest**: BroadcasteReceiver for stopping service.
- **ScheduleUnit**: A record for holding a start and end date for a scheduling.

I tested my service with simply calling:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceTest.class);
    startService(intent);
```

And it works fine... however, i cannot make scheduling work with alarm manager.

Here are the classes:

**ScheduleUnit:**

```
public class ScheduleUnit {

public String id;
public Date dateStart, dateEnd; // Start and end date for a scheduling

public ScheduleUnit(String id, String dateStart, String dateEnd) {
    this.id = id;
    this.dateStart = stringToDate(dateStart);
    this.dateEnd = stringToDate(dateEnd);
}

public Date stringToDate(String dateStr) {

    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
}
```

**ServiceTest:**

```
/**
 * 
 * Simple test service, logging starting, running and destroying.
 */

public class ServiceTest extends Service {

private final String TAG = "MyDebug_Service_Test";
private final boolean DEBUG = true;

private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log("Service is actually still alive.");

        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }

};

private void log(Object o) {
    if (DEBUG) {
        Log.i(TAG, o.toString());
        FileLogger.appendToLog(o);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    log("onCreate");
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(runnable);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    log("onStartCommand");

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    log("onDestroy");

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

}
```

**ServiceStopBroadcastReceiverTest:**

```
/**
 * Simple broadcast receiver for catching a broadcast to stop the service.
 * 
 * 
 */

public class ServiceStopBroadcastReceiverTest extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("MyDebug_ServiceStopBroadcastReceiverTest", "onReceive ran, Calling stopService now.");
    context.stopService(new Intent(context, ServiceTest.class));

}

}
```

**ServiceSchedulerTest:**

```
public class ServiceSchedulerTest {

    private static ServiceSchedulerTest mInstance;
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private Context ctx;

    private static String TAG = "MyDebug_ServiceSchedulerTest";
    private static boolean DEBUG = true;

    private static void log(Object o) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, o.toString());
        }
    }

    // Singleton pattern
    private ServiceSchedulerTest(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx.getApplicationContext();
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    }

    // Singleton pattern
    public static ServiceSchedulerTest getInstance(Context ctx) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new ServiceSchedulerTest(ctx);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void scheduleService(ScheduleUnit scheduleUnit) {



        /**
         * First part, scheduling START service
         */

        // unique Id for Start
        int uniqueIdForStart = (int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

        log("Scheduling to START service at date: " + scheduleUnit.dateStart + " with request code: " + uniqueIdForStart);

        // StartDate in millis
        long millisToStartDate = scheduleUnit.dateStart.getTime();

        log("Scheduling start in millis: "+millisToStartDate);

        // Start intent for service
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(ctx, ServiceSchedulerTest.class);

        // Pending intent, with uniqueId and intent parameter for alarmManager's set function
        PendingIntent startPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ctx, uniqueIdForStart, startIntent, 0);

        // Setting the actual alarm with the start PendingIntent
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millisToStartDate, startPendingIntent);
        // /////////////////////////////////

        /**
         * Second part, scheduling STOP service
         */

        // unique Id for Start
        int uniqueIdForEnd = (int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        //Increment to make sure it is different from uniqueIdForStart
        uniqueIdForEnd++;

        log("Scheduling to STOP service at date: " + scheduleUnit.dateEnd + " with request code: " + uniqueIdForEnd);

        // EndDate in millis
        long millisToEndDate = scheduleUnit.dateEnd.getTime();

        log("Scheduling end in millis: "+millisToEndDate);

        // End intent for service -> calling a broadcast reciver to actually stop the service
        Intent endIntent = new Intent(ctx, ServiceStopBroadcastReceiverTest.class);

        // Penidng intent, with the uniqueId and the intent paramter for alarmManager'set function
        PendingIntent endPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, uniqueIdForEnd, endIntent, 0);

        // Setting alarm manager to call the Service stopping
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millisToEndDate, endPendingIntent);

    }

}
```

Logging:

> 04-08 15:13:46.681: I/MyDebug_ServiceSchedulerTest(27581): Scheduling
>   to START service at date: Wed Apr 08 15:15:00 CEST 2015 with request
>   code: -1725282887
>
> 04-08 15:13:46.682: I/MyDebug_ServiceSchedulerTest(27581): Scheduling
>   start in millis: 1428498900000
>
> 04-08 15:13:46.687: I/MyDebug_ServiceSchedulerTest(27581): Scheduling
>   to STOP service at date: Wed Apr 08 15:16:00 CEST 2015 with request
>   code: -1725282881
>
> 04-08 15:13:46.687: I/MyDebug_ServiceSchedulerTest(27581): Scheduling
>   end in millis: 1428498960000

Problem is:

The service actually never gets called, it never runs.

Help me if you can.

**E D I T:**

As *ci_* mentioned below i accidentally **added wrong class to my pendingIntent's getService method.** Changing it to the **actual Service it is working fine**

Comment: `startPendingIntent` is a pending intent created with `PendingIntent.getService()`, but the `Intent` passed is not a `Service`.

Comment: No, it is fine, from the docs of `PendingIntent.getService:`

**"Parameters: intent An Intent describing the service to be started."**

Comment: No, it's not fine. Read the rest of the docs: "Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a service, like calling Context.startService()." You're passing `ServiceSchedulerTest`, which is not a `Service`.

Comment: Oh my god i thought it is `ServiceTest.class`, add this as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ServiceSchedulerTest` you're trying to get a service `PendingIntent` for `ServiceSchedulerTest`, which is most likely a typo and should have been `ServiceTest`

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(ctx, ServiceSchedulerTest.class);
```

should most likely be:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(ctx, ServiceTest.class);
```